# vba code to click on each tabs( View Contact) in webpage using selenium vba

Tags: vba, selenium

I want to click on all View Contact tabs in webpage,there are 10 View Contact tabs in webpage. each tabs having the same html code
Please see the image of webpage.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTocP.jpg

my html code:-

```html
<input type="button" class="boxOpener btn blue b" style="width: 150px;font-size: 14px;" value="View Contact">
<input type="button" class="boxOpener btn blue b" style="width: 150px;font-size: 14px;" value="View Contact">
```

The HTML is :

```html
<div id="226235653" class="lmsSearchTpl1">
  <div class="lmsSearchTplDetail">
    <div class="lmsTplQualify">
      <span class="hasEllipse">
<i class="lmsIcons requirement-verified-tuple"></i>
<div id="expelipse" class="infoTip f12 ital tool_tip6" style="width: 200px; top: 40px; left: -15px; display: none;"><em class="upPin"></em><em class="text">Verified: Lead’s information has been verified by our system.</em></div>
</span>
      <!-- Classes of such icons : mobile-verified-tuple, mobile-exist-tuple, requirement-verified-tuple -->
    </div>
    <div class="clearAfter">
      <div class="bulkSmsTupleCheckboxDiv lf" style="width: 4%;display: none;">
        <input type="checkbox" class="bulkSmsTupleCheckbox" id="tuplecheckbox_226235653" value="226235653_27395571" onclick="leadSrch.listUnlistForSms(this)">
      </div>
      <div class="lf lmsIndName">
        Arjun Singh </div>
      <div class="rf lmsTplDate">
        <span>Received : </span>
        <span class="sb" style="color: #666;">10 Dec 2017</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearAfter rel">
      <div class="lf lmsTypeAndAddress f13">
        <div>
          <span class="sb"><span>Residential Apartment</span></span>
          <span>for</span>
          <span class="sb">Rent</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>City :</span>
          <span class="sb"><span>Kolkata South</span></span>
          <span>  |  </span>
          <span>Locality : </span>
          <span class="sb"><span>Tollygunge</span></span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="rf">
        <i></i>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="clr" style="height: 10px;"></div>
    <div class="clearAfter tabularFacts">
      <div>
        <div>Min Budget</div>
        <div>5,000 </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>Bedrooms</div>
        <div>2 BHK</div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div>Car Parking</div>
        <div>----</div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div>Furnishing</div>
        <div><span>Unfurnished</span></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>Tenant Type</div>
        <div>----</div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div>Projects</div>
        <div>----</div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div>Preferred Call Time</div>
        <div>Any Time</div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div>Site Visit </div>
        <div>----</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearAfter tabularOtherFacts mt20">
      <div>
        <span>Requirements : </span>
        <span>----</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="lmsViewMoreLine clearAfter">

    <div class="lf" style="padding: 0px 15px 5px 15px;">
      <a id="vmr_226235653" href="javascript:void(0);" class="vmr inlineMiddleChild lmsViewMore">
        <span> 
                            View more requirements from this buyer
                        </span>
        <i class="lmsIcons lmsBlueArrow ml5"></i>
      </a>
      <div class="clr" style="height: 10px;"></div>
      <div id="vmrWrap_226235653" class="otherAssociateLeads" style="display:none;">
        <div class="clr pdt8"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rf lmsSearchControls">
      <div class="lmsCredits">
        <span class=" numCredits">1.00</span>
        <span>Credit(s)</span>
      </div>
      <div class="lmsLookout">
        <i class="lmsEye lmsIcons"></i>
        <span id="viewTime">0 Time(s)</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="button" class="boxOpener btn blue b" style="width: 150px;font-size: 14px;" value="View Contact">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lmsTplConfirm clr confirmBox" style="background-color: rgba(134, 134, 134, 0.05);display: none;">
      <div class="lmsTplConfirmQues">
        <div class="f13 grey">
          You cannot view this lead's contact details.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="lmsTplConfirmAns clearAfter" style="display: none">
        <div class=" clearfix" style="display:block">
          <div class="clr f14 lf grey"> Some error has occurred. Please refresh your search and try again. </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us more of the `outerHTML` including the names like `Arjun Singh` and others.

Comment: Hi Debanjan thanks for the reply. please see below my complete html code

Comment: You should edit the Question and update the `HTML` within the Question area only. You must not paste the `HTML` in the Answer area as it is liable to be deleted being marked as **Not an Answer**

Comment: Hi DebanjanB i am trying to delete but it still not deleted.Please help me how to delete.

Comment: Paste the `HTML` with in the Question area afresh. The `HTML` in the Answer area is already deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click the **`View Contact`** button for `Arjun Singh` you can use the following `xpath` :

```
"//div[@class='lf lmsIndName']//following::input[@class='boxOpener btn blue b']"
```

Comment: Hi DebanjanB thanks for the reply your code is working fine but it click only one tab but i want to click all 10 tabs present in webpage in loop.Please help!!!